# Orleans parallel reads

Tags: orleans

I am new to orleans so forgive me if this is a dumb question.

I recently watched a tutorial where the presenter created an aggregate actor that was used to query a collection of state of other individual actors.

Since actors cannot execute actions in parallel is this really an anti pattern to do reads in this way? Or is orleans so fast because it can query in memory that it does not really matter that reads are not in parallel?

Comment: Maybe you are talking about [Reentrant-Grains](https://orleanscn.github.io/orleans/Documentation/Advanced-Concepts/Reentrant-Grains.html) ?

Comment: @Murdock can you link the tutorial for context?

Answer (score 2):

You are totally right, that Grains are thread-safe. And there are some ways to override this rule, however the flow should be fully understood to avoid unexpected behaviour and issues, such as deadlocks.

One of the potential way to allow State readings in parrallel is `[ReadOnly]` attribute. It allows you to add `[ReadOnly]` to your method for safe concurrent reads of grain state across multiple clients without the risk of data corruption due to multiple clients attempting to write to the same state at the same time.

This improves the performance of read operations in a distributed Orleans environment by enabling parallel reads between other `[ReadOnly]` methods across multiple clients.

Note:

When a method is marked with the `[ReadOnly]` attribute, Orleans generates code to enforce the read-only constraint, which prevents any attempt to modify the state of the grain within the method. If you try to modify the grain state within a `[ReadOnly]` method, the generated code will detect the attempt to modify the state and throw an exception at runtime.

You can get more details about Orleans Concurrency by the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/orleans.concurrency?view=orleans-7.0), however there is a little pure description of some points.